# The first char of the string from a text file be eat after the shell while loop into second interate

Tags: linux, shell

It is a very strange question.
I am trying to use turbostat(from linux kernel: linux/tools/power/x86/turbostat) to log the energy usage for some program.

for simplify, I use the stress(you can get it: sudo apt install stress) as the program been test.

I have 4 sub-folders, they are 1/, 2/, 3/, 4/, each folder have a test suite need to run, I have create a text file which have the test list.

the turbostat link:
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/tools/power/x86/turbostat

the turbostat was build and copy to /usr/bin, and run: sudo chmod u+s turbostat in /usr/bin for permission.

my folder struct:

```
topfolder
|-testlist.txt
|-runall.sh
|-1/
|-2/
|-3/
|-4/
```

the runall.sh:

```
# run loop
reset
_dir=$(pwd)

while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo ''
    echo $line
    cd $line
    echo stress --cpu 1 --timeout 5 > doit.sh
    turbostat -S -i 0.5 --show Bzy_MHz,CorWatt,PkgWatt -o $line.tsv&
    sh doit.sh
    cd $_dir
done < "testlist.txt"
```

the content of testlist.txt:

```
1
2
3
4
```

output of runall.sh:

```
1
stress: info: [1729] dispatching hogs: 1 cpu, 0 io, 0 vm, 0 hdd
turbostat: Insanely slow TSC rate, TSC stops in idle?
You can disable all c-states by booting with "idle=poll"
or just the deep ones with "processor.max_cstate=1"
stress: info: [1729] successful run completed in 5s
[2]+  Exit 253                turbostat -S -i 0.5 --show Bzy_MHz,CorWatt,PkgWatt -o $line.tsv


stress: info: [1735] dispatching hogs: 1 cpu, 0 io, 0 vm, 0 hdd
stress: info: [1735] successful run completed in 5s
```

at the first interate, the $line is "1", but in the next interate, $line would be a blank string.

if change the testlist.txt to:

```
1
12
13
14
```

the $line would be 1 2 3 4, the first char been eat from second interate.

why this happen? and how can I fix it?
My OS: ubuntu 22.04.1 with kernel 5.19.3

update:
when change:

```
turbostat -i 0.5 --show Bzy_MHz,CorWatt,PkgWatt -o $line.tsv &
sh doit.sh
```

to:

```
turbostat -i 0.5 --show Bzy_MHz,CorWatt,PkgWatt -o $line.tsv sh doit.sh
```

the while loop run normal,but, I can not get the log for each 0.5 second(-i 0.5) which what I need, turbostat only output a avg results.

I think turbostat with "&" would eat the first char ?

update 2:
Thanks William Pursell, add yes|Q before turbostat... does allow the loop run normal.

There is still a question, turbostat can not output the results what I expect . Maybe I need to open another question for it.

Comment: I bet testlist.txt has Windows style CRLF line endings.

Comment: Does `turbostat` or `doit.sh` consume any data from stdin?

Comment: @Shawn it is UNIX EOL, I checked.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I am a rookie here, I don't know how to check it and how to find a workaround...

Comment: Try redirecting the input of both commands with `</dev/null` to prevent them from eating anything from stdin.

Comment: @Barmar wow, do you mean turbostat -S -i 0.5 --show Bzy_MHz,CorWatt,PkgWatt -o $line.tsv </dev/null and sh doit.sh </dev/null ， that cause the turbostat always run and can not break it through ctrl+c, I have to close the ssh seesion.

Comment: `turbostat` allows you to stop it by typing `q`, so it reads a character from stdin each time it loops. If it can't read from stdin, it just loops continuously. You're running it in the background so you can't stop it with Ctl-c.

Comment: This looks like turbostat is the culprit ....

Comment: If it's currently working as you want, you might simply try `echo y | turbostat ...` or `yes | turbostat ...` (or use some other suitable character).

Comment: @Barmar, I found just type "q" can not stop normal run turbostat, I need to press Enter follow "Q" key to quit turbostat.

Comment: Another common technique is to let the original stdin propagate through and use a different fd for the while loop: `while IFS=  read -r line <&3; do ... done 3< testlist.txt`

Comment: try `yes Q | turbostat ...`

Comment: `turbostat ... & turbostat_pid=$!` lets you `kill "$turbostat_pid"` to stop it later.

Comment: @WilliamPursell ']yes Q |' works, thank you. I still need to find out why turbostat can not output the result per 0.5s that like it run not in a shell script.